# using neo4j on appharbor

Tags: neo4j, appharbor

Curious about using app harbor for my web api backed by a neo4j database.  If I host an instance of neo4j on an amazon ec2 instance, how can I secure a connection between that ec2 instance and my app harbor worker?  can I set the geographical region on an app harbor application to minimize latency on the network between the db and the app?

Is there a recommended or hosted instance of neo4j that I should be using with app harbor apps?  I know that heroku will have a hosted neo4j solution soon, would there be any issues if my app harbor app were to use the heroku hosted neo4j service?

Comment: did you implement frissm solution? how did it go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could conceivably create an app on Heroku and provision the [Neo4j add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/neo4j) there, then copy-paste the connectionstring and consume the neo4j instance from your AppHarbor app.

Alternatively, you can run Neo4J yourself, and open up to AppHarbor application servers. The instructions are here: http://support.appharbor.com/kb/tips-and-tricks/application-server-ips-ec2-configuration

Comment: would that give access to our Neo4j ec2 instance from ALL app harbor applications, even ones that our not ours?

Comment: No, you could put the access keys (securing the EC2 instance) into the environment config of your AppHarbor instance, much like on Heroku I think, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/neo4j#addon-settings.